# How to use Symfony2 with MongoDB on cloudControl?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, cloudcontrol

I would like to use Symfony2 and MongoDB on a cloudControl (PaaS provider like heroku) container. Now [Symfony2 supports the usage of MongoDB](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html):

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

And as MongoDB is a PaaS AddOn, I don't have static connection credentials. They're generated by the container. cloudControl offers this way to access the credentials in PHP:

```
$credfile = file_get_contents($_ENV['CRED_FILE'], false);
$credentials = json_decode($credfile, true);
$uri = $credentials["MONGOLAB"]["MONGOLAB_URI"];
$m = new Mongo($uri);
$db = $m->selectDB(myDbName);
$col = new MongoCollection($db, myCollection);
```

How can I get these dynamically fetched credentials into Symfony2's `config.yml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to use [Symfony2 Miscellaneous Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration).

So, create `app/config/credentials.php` file with below content:

```
<?php
if (isset($_ENV['CRED_FILE'])) {

    // read the credentials file
    $string = file_get_contents($_ENV['CRED_FILE'], false);
    if ($string == false) {
        throw new Exception('Could not read credentials file');
    }

    // the file contains a JSON string, decode it and return an associative array
    $creds = json_decode($string, true);

    // overwrite config server param with mongolab uri
    $uri = $creds["MONGOLAB"]["MONGOLAB_URI"];
    $container->setParameter('doctrine_mongodb.connections.default.server', $uri);
}
```

Then in your `app/config/config.yml` add:

```
imports:
    - { resource: credentials.php }
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Looks really nice, will try that out. But btw: Why are you checking `!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])`?

Comment: We have used it to distinguish between PaaS and local env - you can ignore it!

Comment: Okay, and how about the `$container`? Is the container automatically available in that PHP file or do I have to inject it manually?

Comment: It should be automatically available.

Comment: Yeah, just tested it. The `$container` is known and doesn't has to be injected. Wow, this is such an easy way. I used to dynamically set some parameters via Services and kernelListeners, but this is easy as hell; thanks a million!

Comment: I get this error  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service definition "doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager" does not exist.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ikollect/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php on line 48`   although I set `$container->setParameter('doctrine_mongodb.document_managers.default.auto_mapping', true);`